# Android creating Circular layout

Tags: android

I am trying to create a circular layout that always stay's on the screen.

To do so, I have created a System overlay and added a button.

But, now I want to make it round.

Either I can use 4 different ImageView and and textView and add both to FrameLayout.

I read somewhere that simple things like this can be made by XML.

How do I do it?

I want to achieve something like this :

[image]

EDIT

After following your guide I was able to achieve this : 
[image]

But I am not satisfied by the way I used.
What I did was created 2 shaped (background, forground) and added them to a layerlist.

BACKGROUND

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<solid android:color="#50000000" />

</shape>
```

FORGROUND

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<solid android:color="#99009900" />

</shape>
```

LIST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/circleback">
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circlefront"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp">
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Then, I used a framelayout and added 2 textview.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:text="@string/data_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="@string/band"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then inflated them by service. But I am not happy with the textposition and the fact that I have to random hit and trial to find center of circle.

I'll later add pinch to zoom to view so, I really want to find a way that text align itself to centre of circle.

Comment: post code, not just statement/requirement. What have u tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a shape drawable (in the `res/drawable` folder) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" 
   <solid android:color="#ff00ff00 />
</shape>
```

See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: When you set the drawable suggested by Marcin as the drawable for your TextView (you just need a TextView and nothing else) make sure you specify the same values, in **dp**, for both **layout_width** and **layout_height**.